# HTML Tabbed Description

Tags: shopify

I am having trouble adding a tabbed description to my Shopify store, I have tried the options below with no luck!

The first issue is I am not sure I am using the split tag correctly, as the function doesn't pull the code.

Secondly, the tabbed description displays all the information in one view. Doesn't seem to be in a box format more of an overflow?

Any help will be grateful! I am not a coder, but I gave it a try. Can you help?

Product.liquid

Option-1: Replace {% section 'product-template' %} with HTML below

Option-2: No replacement just add

Or
Product-template.liquid

Option-3: Replace {% section 'product-template' %} with HTML below

Option-4: No replacement just add

Or 
Product description HTML editor

Option-5: Add HTML

HTML

```
<div id="product_tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab_1"><a href="#tabs-1"><h4>Description</h4></a></li>
    <li class="tab_2"><a href="#tabs-2"><h4>Specs</h4></a></li>
    <li class="tab_3"><a href="#tabs-3"><h4>Shipping</h4></a></li>
    <li class="tab_4"><a href="#tabs-4"><h4>Returns/Refunds</h4></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    {% if product.description contains '<!-- split -->' %} 
      {{ description[0] }} 
    {% else %} 
    <p>No Content</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    {% if product.description contains '<!-- split -->' %} 
      {{ description[1] }}
    {% else %}
      <p>No Content</p>
    {% endif %} 
  </div>
                   <div id="tabs-3">
    {{ pages.shipping-policy.content }}
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-4">
    {{ pages.refund-policy.content }}
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS
Add to Theme.scss.liquid

```
#product_tabs > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}
#product_tabs > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
#product_tabs > ul > li h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
#product_tabs > ul > li.ui-tabs-active {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: I added the tabs one by one in the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me as though there is nothing that is making the tabs active or inactive. Did you forget to post some of your code? If not it explains why everything is being displayed all at once. If nothing is telling it when to show it will just display everything back to back like you described.

For the explanation of how split works see [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAm-TV14DaAhULjlkKHWK3AWUQygQIPTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.shopify.com%2Fthemes%2Fliquid%2Ffilters%2Fstring-filters%23split&usg=AOvVaw3dCSSuj6OOOtbDelLmQ_wG). Essentially it can pull from an array; however I don't know why your product description would be an array.

The shopify official help center created a post on making tabs that has worked for many people in the past see [here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/products/features/add-tabs-to-product-descriptions).

Comment: I have been struggling with the active part is this an include function that is needed in the theme.liquid? My first two tabs will be changing all the time so I want them to pull from the product.description with the split function and the second set of tabs will be the same

Comment: Outdated - Delete

Comment: I could have my tabs all pull from product.description and have the description seperated by four splits - so really I need to work out how to make it active